# Questions with integral2 , Double, Syms and Dot calucations

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I got 2 questions here.
1. If I have y = a*x^2 + 5. What function can make it into y = a.*x.^2 +5. As you seen, dot was inserted.

2. It's easy, but kinda diffcult to describe, but please have patience with me. Thank you so much.
   First, let me make a very simple example of my problem.
   If I want to calucate Y = *F(x=1)*+ 2.^2,  and I know  *F(x=1)* = a+b,(a and b are syms). This means Y = a + b + 4. Problem is here,
   Matlab give me error if I write down as.

   F = function( .... ); <====  output of function is F(X=1), and = *F(x=1)* = a+b
   Y = integral2( F + 2.^2, .. , .. ,..)
   However, if I just copy the output of F as 
   Y = integral2( a+b + 2.^2, .. , .. ,..)
   Now it works!!!

Ok. Please allow me to talk about my code here.  I am trying to find a double interation by using integral2. One part of my equcation(which is Y) is from another int output(which is F). Matlab will give *ERROR* for code below:

```
   clear all; 

  a=4; 
  la1=1/(pi*500^2); la2= la1*5;
  p1=25; p2=p1/25;
  sgma2=10^(-11);
  index=1;
  g=2./a;
  syms r u1 u2  
  powe= -2 ;  
  seta= 10^powe;
  xNor = ( (u2./u1).^(a./2) + 1    ).^(2./a);
  x = (xNor).^(0.5) * seta^(-1/a);

    fun1 =  r./(1+ r.^a );
    out1 = int(fun1, x, Inf) ; %== This is my F in my example

  q=pi.*(la1.*p1.^(2./a)+la2.*p2.^(2./a));

  yi = @(u2,u1) exp(-u2.*(1+2.*...
        ( out1  )./...      %=== out1 is the problem here. 
        (  (( (u2./u1).^(a./2) + 1    ).^(2./a)).*seta.^(-2./a)))).*...
                  exp(-sgma2.*q.^(-a./2).* seta.*u2.^(a./2)./...
          ((( (u2./u1).^(a./2) + 1    ).^(2./a)).^(a./2))  ); 

  maxF =@(u2) u2;
  out2 = integral2(yi,0,Inf,0 ,maxF) % == this is Y in my previous example.
```

However, since I know the out1 = pi/4 - atan(10*(u2^2/u1^2 + 1)^(1/2))/2 (no dot,1/2, not 1./2). Instead of writing down out1, I will just type the equaction and add dot in the

```
  yi = @(u2,u1) exp(-u2.*(1+2.*...
          (  pi./4 - atan(10.*(u2.^2./u1.^2 + 1).^(1./2))./2     )./...   %=== not "out1"
          (  (( (u2./u1).^(a./2) + 1    ).^(2./a)).*seta.^(-2./a)))).*...
                    exp(-sgma2.*q.^(-a./2).* seta.*u2.^(a./2)./...
            ((( (u2./u1).^(a./2) + 1    ).^(2./a)).^(a./2))  );
```

Now the code is working!!!! The final output is = 0.9957.
Dear friends, I already spend a long time on this, but I still can not find out the problem.  Could you please take a deeper look for me. Please copy the code to you matlab and test.  Thank you so much.

Below is the error given by matlab, if I just use "out1" in yi = @(u2,u1) ......

```
  Error using integralCalc/finalInputChecks (line 511)
  Input function must return 'double' or 'single' values. Found 'sym'.

  Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 315)
                  finalInputChecks(x,fx);

  Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 133)
              [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

  Error in integralCalc (line 76)
          [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AtoBInvTransform,interval);

  Error in
  integral2Calc>@(xi,y1i,y2i)integralCalc(@(y)fun(xi*ones(size(y)),y),y1i,y2i,opstruct.integralOptions)
  (line 18)
  innerintegral = @(x)arrayfun(@(xi,y1i,y2i)integralCalc( ...

  Error in
  integral2Calc>@(x)arrayfun(@(xi,y1i,y2i)integralCalc(@(y)fun(xi*ones(size(y)),y),y1i,y2i,opstruct.integralOptions),x,ymin(x),ymax(x))
  (line 18)
  innerintegral = @(x)arrayfun(@(xi,y1i,y2i)integralCalc( ...

  Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 314)
                  fx = FUN(t);

  Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 133)
              [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

  Error in integralCalc (line 84)
          [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AToInfInvTransform,interval);

  Error in integral2Calc>integral2i (line 21)
  [q,errbnd] = integralCalc(innerintegral,xmin,xmax,opstruct.integralOptions);

  Error in integral2Calc (line 8)
      [q,errbnd] = integral2i(fun,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,optionstruct);

  Error in integral2 (line 107)
      Q = integral2Calc(fun,xmin,xmax,yminfun,ymaxfun,opstruct);

  Error in ref7_equ11n2 (line 129)
         out2 = integral2(yi,0,Inf,0 ,maxF)
```

Comment: To get a more satisfactory answer you should rather ask along those lines: "I want to evaluate the following integral..[Here you write down the equation you are trying to solve, **NOT** the code that's not working!]. I have already tried doing the following: [Here you put your code], but it isn't working because of ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of the function `integral2` states:

> integral2 - **Numerically** evaluate double integral

You won't be able to use `integral2` with symbolic expressions, unless you convert them to function handles using [matlabfunction](http://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html).

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply. But what do you mean by that? out1 is a function with symbolic expression. right?

Comment: @sunson29: Yes, and numerical evaluation is not compatible with symbolic evaluation. So this is why you get the error: "*Input function must return 'double' or 'single' values. Found 'sym'.*", which can be interpreted as: "You can't use `integral2` with `syms` directly". This will only work if you convert to a function handle using `matlabfunction(out1)`.

Comment: thank you so much! It's working!  Btw, How did you know this?  I wanna to learn the reason. sothat I know how to solve the problem in the future.

Comment: 1. I read the error message, which says: "*Input function must return 'double' or 'single' values. Found 'sym'.*". This will give you a hint, that symbolic expressions might not work. 2. I type `doc integral2`, to check what the parameter types of `integral2` are. In this case it clearly states that the input needs to be a *function handle*.
3. I google for "*matlab convert symbolic to function handle*", which gives me http://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html as the first link.

Comment: @sunson29: By the way: If my answer solved your issue, please consider accepting it by clicking the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.